# Integrate function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, integral

I am new to Matlab. I would like to integrate a function. I try int() and integrate() but they all cause problems to me - not enough parameters or other different errors, I have tried many combinations with documentation. My current code is the following, I would like to be able to pass numbers p and q to res and obtain a numerical result:

```
syms x;
w = 1;
hbar = 1.054571800*10^(-34);
k = (w/(pi*hbar))^(1/4);
e = @(q) (w*q/hbar)^(1/2);
waveF = @(q) k*exp(-feval(e,q)*feval(e,q)*1/2.0)*1.0/1;
func = @(p,q) waveF(q-x/2)*waveF(q+x/2)*exp(1i*p*x/(hbar));

res = @(p,q) int(func(p,q), x = -Inf..Inf);
```

Currently " x = " is indicated as en error although it seems ok according to the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) in concert with the [Symbolic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) and have mistakenly used the [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad-1.html) version of [`int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/int.html), which is actually generating the error, when you wanted the [Symbolic `int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html).

While mixing anonymous functions with Symbolic calls is not illegal, I think you would be better served by sticking to one paradigm of computation at a time:

1. Purely Symbolic version using Symbolic functions:

   ```
   syms x p q e(q) waveF(q) func(p,q) res(p,q);
   w         = sym(1);
   hbar      = sym('1.054571800E-34');
   k         = (w/(pi*hbar))^(1/4);
   e(q)      = sqrt(w*q/hbar);
   waveF(q)  = k*exp(-e(q)^2/2);
   func(p,q) = waveF(q-x/2)*waveF(q+x/2)*exp(1i*p*x/(hbar));
   res(p,q)  = int(func(p,q),x,-Inf,Inf);
   ```

   I wrapped the value of `hbar` in quotes to force the use of the supplied value and not the nearest rational representation that would've been coerced during computation.

---

2. Purely numeric version using anonymous functions and the numeric [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function:

   ```
   w     = 1;
   hbar  = 1.054571800E-34;
   k     = (w/(pi*hbar)).^(1/4);
   e     = @(q) sqrt(w*q/hbar);
   waveF = @(q) k*exp(-e(q).^2/2);
   func  = @(p,q,x) waveF(q-x/2).*waveF(q+x/2).*exp(1i*p*x/hbar);
   res   = @(p,q) integral(@(x) func(p,q,x),-Inf,Inf);
   ```

---

Both of these version generate `NaN` when `res` is evaluated, but that's probably a shortcoming of the integrand. However, the functional forms and ideas behind the above scripts won't change with different integrands.